# Change Google map marker

Tags: google-maps

How i change my marker in google map.is possible to add our custome image to map?

Thanks,
Companion

Comment: Please read the documentation before asking obvious questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it is really simple - see http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#SimpleIcons

example straight from the google docs

```
var image = 'beachflag.png';
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: image
});
```

if you want to do more complex stuff, you can also extend googles overlay classes and perform custom rendering ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a the way I use to use my own custom-designed markers in place of Google’s default markers.

Add this line of code:

```
 var icon = new GIcon();
      icon.image = "http://yourwebsite.com/logo.png";
      icon.shadow = "http://youwebsite.com/shadow.png";
      icon.iconSize = new GSize(50, 28);
      icon.shadowSize = new GSize(68, 28);
      icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(37, 59);
      icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(31, 8);
```

Adjust the GSize for both iconSize and shadowSize if necessary. The first number in parentheses defines the width of your marker and the second number defines the height (both in pixels).

Now, add this line of code:

```
var marker = new GMarker(point, icon);
```

Just after this line:

```
function createMarker(point, name, address)
```

Hope that helps! You can see a blog post I wrote about this at http://icode4you.net/developing-a-custom-store-locator-map-using-your-own-custom-markers-instead-of-googles-default-markers, just leave a comment if you have any questions or problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you most definitely can:

Try this

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("YOUR MAP ID"));

var icon = new GIcon();
icon.image = "IMAGE PATH - RELETIVE OR ABSOLUTE";
icon.iconSize = new GSize(25, 30);
icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);

var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(Latitude, Longitude), { draggable: false, title: YOURTITLEHERE, icon: icon });
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, i have added ur code but now i get two markers, default baloon marker and the custom marker i have added.How i remove the default marker.

Comment: how do you add your default marker? can you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: hi,I have already attached an image to my marker,but when i change the marker with a custom icon, the image is not showing when clicks on the marker.Do you know what the issue?

Answer (score 0):

From Google Map API V2, this could also be don easily with the object MarkerOptions:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .position(new LatLng( ...your_lat...  ,  ...your_long... ))
       .title( "marker title" )
       .icon( BitmapDescriptorFactory
           .fromResource( R.drawable.custom_icon )));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can

```
marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')
```

Or as part of marker init:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: 'http://...'
});
```