# How to place my own icons for google default icons in map?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I am trying to make an app that could identify nearby bus stations. Google map has a specific icon to denote them. I some how wish to place my own icon above google map's default icon using overlay or something else.
How I can do this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483963/is-there-any-default-google-map-marker-in-android-same-as-in-iphone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801989/change-google-map-marker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442016/how-to-get-default-google-map-marker-to-represent-users-current-location http://androidforums.com/htc-amaze-4g/508614-change-default-map-viewer-locations-google-maps.html

Comment: I have an idea and am trying to code it out.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial will teach you all you need to know about how to add your own custom icon.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

It teaches you every part that you need to know from how to add the icon to how to have it relate to your map view.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply but I don't have any geo coordinates saved before hand I want to search it using the icon used by google map to denote the bus stand.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. How are you going to add icons to a map if you don't have their lat/long locations? So you're going to be querying a geolocation of where you are, then find nearby bus stops, and then do something with that?